# dynamic order by in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

so, i have a database that has a column called "label" (which is of a JSONB type) in which i store multi-language data like this `{"es": "babababa", "fr": "yuyuyuyu"}`

i have a function that generates the sql template and in that function i have a `.replace` JS method like this one : `templateString.replace(/\{\{ORDER BY\}\}/g, ' \{\{\? (sql.sortString) \}\} ORDER BY \{\{<<<sql.sortString\}\} \{\{\?\}\}')`

the `sql.sortString` variable is a `.join(', ')` JS method on some developper-defined array : `defaultSort : ['id', 'type']`

all this works very well for normal columns, however, for JSONB columns, i have tried multiple approaches but the only one close to succession is a postgresql function that returns a string :

```
create or replace function get_label(some_json anyelement, lang text, _label text)
    returns text 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    as 
$func$
declare 
    result_query text := ' ';
begin 
    result_query := (
        case pg_typeof(some_json)
        when 'jsonb'::regtype then
            result_query || '"' || _label || '"' || '->>' || '''' || lang || ''''
        else 
            result_query || '"' || _label || '"'
        end
    );
    return result_query;
end;
$func$;
```

the problem is that i cannot seem to make this text returned by the function work, as

```
-- some function generated psql code (for exemple select * from "question")

ORDER BY get_label("label", 'es', 'label');
```

translates to

```
ORDER BY '"label"->>'fr'';
```

and as such, it is not recognized by postgresql as executable code.

i have tried with

```
ORDER BY EXECUTE get_label("label", 'es', 'label');
```

but no luck either.

i have tried to alter the psql function so that it returns either a QUERY, either a SETOF and at the last line, it does a `RETURN EXECUTE QUERY ...` or even `RETURN EXECUTE NEXT ...` but to no avail.

**EDIT 1 :**
exemple of query fed to the template generator function :

```
WITH mealtypes AS (
  SELECT
          "MealType"."id"                 AS "id",
          "MealType"."label"              AS "label",
          "MealType"."extId"              AS "extId",
          "MealType"."type"               AS "type",
          "MealType"."isActive"           AS "isActive"
    FROM  "MealType"
  WHERE
    "MealType"."type" IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND "MealType"."isActive" = true
)

SELECT
  *
  FROM  mealtypes 
{{ORDER BY}}
```

**EDIT 2:**

the template after the JS function

```
WITH mealtypes AS (
  SELECT
          "MealType"."id"                 AS "id",
          "MealType"."label"              AS "label",
          "MealType"."extId"              AS "extId",
          "MealType"."type"               AS "type",
          "MealType"."isActive"           AS "isActive"
    FROM  "MealType"
  WHERE
    "MealType"."type" IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND "MealType"."isActive" = true
)

SELECT
  *
FROM  
  mealtypes 
ORDER BY
    get_label("type", 'fr', 'type'), 
    get_label("id", 'fr', 'id'), 
    get_label("label", 'fr', 'label')
```

Comment: how does your query know which table/relation you are invoking column "label" from?

Comment: that is developpers responsability to make sure that if in the `defaultSort` array there is a column to sort by, that the column in question be present in the template (either as alias or column)

Comment: Please update the question with an example of a failing query and the associated error messasge. The code for the template generator function might also be helpful.

Comment: in my opinion, the function is irrelevant, but i might be wrong.
the idea is that today, the function replaces `{{ORDER BY}}` by a string concatenation `ORDER BY defaultSort.join(', ')`
and this is limiting for JSONB type columns. 
the idea is to have a dynamically generated ORDER BY

as for the failing query (see my question here above) it is not failing and i don't have an error message, the result is that the query is not ordered by the corresponding `label` column, as what the psql function returns is a string which is not executed by psql

Comment: The generator function is not irrelevant because it, in conjunction with `get_label`, directly produces the query that is failing. The clause that you posted, `ORDER BY '"label"->>'fr'';` should be `ORDER BY "label"->>'fr';`. Having the full code chain is important for determining the source of the single quotes around the JSON element extraction expression.

Comment: but the `'"label"->>'fr'';` as text is not injected by the JS function, but by the psql function.

Comment: Whether an exception is raised or not, the query is failing because it is not producing the expected results. Please post an example of the expected results and the JS function. From the sample output, it is obvious that the JS function is returning the text to call `get_label` (or `GetLabel`, you've used both names) instead of the expected ordering expressions. Also, there is absolutely no reason for the query in the sample template's CTE to have an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: That `get_label` sql function does not make sense. Why not simply build the query string it returns into the query instead of building the function call into the query?

Comment: because of the way the templating is implemented.
you have to write the `{{ORDER BY}}` in the template and pass the `defaultSort` array.
so, the idea of `get_label` is to make the `order by` agnostic of the type of column passed to it.

Comment: @FlorinRinja You haven't shown where `defaultSort` comes from, but the proper solution is to make the `defaultSort` array contain strings like `"label->>'fr' ASC"` instead of `"get_label(type, 'fr', 'type') ASC"`

Comment: in a nutshell, i guess that my question could be resumed to : is it possible to make query-able a string in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: No, it is not possible to execute a query string in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: is there any way, then, to return a query-able output from the `get_label` function ?

Comment: You would need to return the *value* that you want to sort by. Not a query text. But then you could (should!) just drop the function call and directly put the expression that computes the value in the `defaultSort` array, as I suggested.

Comment: @FlorinRinja Though maybe I do not understand what you mean by "query-able output"

Comment: thank you for all these answers.
by "query-able output" i mean a text that can be interpreted by sql without further modifications (as opposed to the text returned today that is just a string that cannot be interpreted by the sql).
i have tried ```create or replace function get_key(some_json anyelement, lang text)
 returns text 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 as 
$func$
begin 
 return some_json->>lang;
exception 
  when others then
     return some_json;  
end;
$func$;```
only that it returns everything as string and as such, the order by is done as `1, 10, 11...` instead of `1, 2, 3...`

Comment: For that you'd use either a different collation, or a function that returns an integer right away. But no, you cannot return text that will be interpreted as SQL - just put that SQL in your `defaultSort` right away.